# Can't Curl docker container running apache from outside the container

Tags: php, docker, curl

I am not able to curl my php that is running Apache from the regular terminal.
Curling localhost inside the container returns the correct results.

docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
dash-api:
 build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
  args:
    - GITHUB_HTTPS_TOKEN=<token>

 volumes:
   - /usr/local/:/usr/local/
   - /app:/var/www/html
 ports:
   - "80:80"
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.2.34-apache AS serve
...
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["apachectl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

the docker logs show a 500 error in the request(from outiside the container)

> 127.0.0.1 - - [25/Nov/2021:12:05:46 +0000] "GET /gateway.php HTTP/1.1" 500 1047 "-" "curl/7.54.0"

But curling a test file(located in the same folder as gateway.php with a single echo in it returns the output.

Comment: Can you show the curl command you're using? Also, what's the output of `docker container ls` and/or `docker ps`? Are you sure you're CURLing the correct IP?

Comment: the containers shows up with ports 
> '0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp'

I'm curling localhost:80

Comment: If the container access log shows that the container received a request with the right path, then the Docker networking setup is correct.  A 500 error is probably something in your code or perhaps the database setup?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add localhost next to port, maybe that will help.

```
version: '3'
services:
dash-api:
 build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
  args:
    - GITHUB_HTTPS_TOKEN=<token>

 volumes:
   - /usr/local/:/usr/local/
   - /app:/var/www/html
 ports:
   - 127.0.0.1:80:80
```